# Cross table in gtsummary with computed data set/weighted count

Tags: r, crosstab, reproducible-research, gtsummary

I would like some more help. I need a cross table in the most publishable format (scientific paper) possible. For these demands I have been using gtsummary.

The data frame I have is a result of previous counts done by other descriptive routines.

[image]

I have tried using tbl_summary, tbl_cross, tbl_strata. However, the one that comes closest to what I need has returned descriptive compute and statistics for the number of rows and not the compute (variable n) of the data frame.

[image]

Sorry, I tried every which way. I even converted the df to wide format. But anyway, I lacked the experience and knowledge to do it!

```
# Data frame
Result <- as.factor(c("Derrota", "Empate", "Vitória", 
            "Derrota", "Empate", "Vitória",
            "Derrota", "Empate", "Vitória"))

Context <- as.factor(c("Overall match", "Overall match", "  
Overall match", "First half", "First half", "First half",   
"After balanced halftime", "After balanced halftime",
"After balanced halftime"))

n <- as.numeric(c(583, 607, 1217,
                  487, 1100, 820, 
                  178, 304, 367))

df <- data.frame(Result, Context, n)

# Definitive table of results
library(gtsummary) # presentation-ready data summary and analytic result tables
df %>%
  select(c('Result',
           'n',
           'Context')) %>% 
     tbl_summary(by=Result)
```

Comment: Hi Christiano, Can you give more details what you need the output to look like? Are you looking for a weighted summary table? Do you need the percentages to be something other than column? More details will help us help you. Also, if you post your question with a reproducible example (i.e. something we can all run on our computers).

Comment: Hi Daniel

Thank you very much for the quick reply. I need only contigency table (Context x Result; factor variable). The data for these variables is in column n (numeric, I called it computed because it comes from a large dataset [>3000], row-by-row). The prop column is unnecessary. 

For exemplification, I need the bottom part of the table (separated by Context of dispute).

Comment: Sorry, I am still not sure what you're looking for exactly. Can you please make a similar table in MS Word, and post a screenshot? I think I can better assist with that.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I put in more details. My wish is for a conventional 3x3 table. Obviously, I can move on to put inferential statistics in it.

Comment: You'll need to mock up an example of what you're looking for. It's not clear to me from your explanation.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Sorry if I am not being clear. Perhaps my difficulty is to operationalize via gtsummary the case of the table with observed cell counts allocated in a variable created for this. I have only two variables (Context and Result) with three levels each (3x3), and with counts of observed cells in variable "n". You presented in your example a table of 4x3x2, respectively: stage, grade and trt. Best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.3.7'

df <- 
  data.frame(
    Result = c("Derrota", "Empate", "Vitória", 
               "Derrota", "Empate", "Vitória",
               "Derrota", "Empate", "Vitória"), 
    Context = c("Overall match", "Overall match", 
                "Overall match", "First half", "First half", "First half",   
                "After balanced halftime", "After balanced halftime",
                "After balanced halftime"), 
    n = c(583, 607, 1217,
          487, 1100, 820, 
          178, 304, 367)
  )

tbl <-
  # convert data frame to survey object that accounts for the weights
  survey::svydesign(~1, data = df, weights = ~n) %>%
  # summarize weighted data
  tbl_svysummary(by = Result, percent = "cell")
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Daniel,

Kind of like this. But, you presented a 4x3x2 table, respectively: stage, grade and trt.

I have only two variables (Context and Result) with three levels each (3x3).

For me, the arrangement in rows or columns will not matter.

Comment: Hi Daniel, good morning from Brazil.

Thank you very much. I didn't know how to communicate with you. I was talking about observed cell count, and technically it was weighted count.

BW,
Cristiano